# vimception ipython notebook extension not working

Tags: key, jupyter-notebook, key-bindings, codemirror

I'm getting the following errors when I try and load the codemirror key bindings via the vimception extension. Any idea what is going wrong? If not, has anyone got the vim keyplugins to work? If so, could they share some working code?

> ReferenceError: Cell is not defined {stack: (...), message: "Cell is
>   not defined"} outputarea.js?v=20150417223853:628 ReferenceError: Cell
>   is not defined {stack: (...), message: "Cell is not defined"} VM271:58
>   Great success codemirror.js?v=20150417223853:4622 Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'attach' of undefined VM272:58 Great success
>   codemirror.js?v=20150417223853:4622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'attach' of undefined